# How to send a number of variables to the workers of a parpool in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Is there a way to send a number of variables to the workers of a parpool?

For example, i might want to tell each worker the total number of workers in the parpool. Or i might have some calculations to be made only once and shared between particular workers or all of them. I feel that for each worker to process the calculations to only be made once is a waste of resources and time.

Eg.

```
*Some calculations processed and a number of variables generated

NumWorkers = 32;
ParallelPool  = parpool(NumWorkers);

*Pass the just variables generated to the workers

pctRunOnAll NumWorkers = 32;
pctRunOnAll ParallelScript
```

At the moment, i tell each worker the total number of workers using the pctRunOnAll command function but i don't like this because i have to change the number of workers in two places, and it's likely to cause an error if i mess up. I would also like to extend this so i can pass a number of variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use eval. It's quite a simple solution and i don't know why i didn't think of it earlier. I've been searching for alternative solutions but i just can't seem to find anything. It's not an elegant solution but it works.

Eg.

```
*Some calculations to obtain the following variables

Variable1 = 12;
Variable2 = 65;
Variable3 = 1205;
Variable4 = 16542;


cmd = ['pctRunOnAll Variable1 = ' num2str(Variable1) ';'];
eval(cmd)
cmd = ['pctRunOnAll Variable2 = ' num2str(Variable2) ';'];
eval(cmd)
cmd = ['pctRunOnAll Variable3 = ' num2str(Variable3) ';'];
eval(cmd)
cmd = ['pctRunOnAll Variable4 = ' num2str(Variable4) ';'];
eval(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
%Some calculations processed and a number of variables generated

NumWorkers = 32;
ParallelPool  = parpool(NumWorkers);

parfor ixWorker = 1:NumWorkers 
    ParrallelFunction(NumWorkers, otherVariable, stillMoreVariables)
end
```

Some notes:

1. I always regret running scripts instead of functions. Whatever you are doing in your script, many things (parallelization is one of them) get easier once you convert it to a function.
2. The `parfor` command is an easy way to run something `N` times, where that is not necessarily the same size as the worker pool. For example, if you are running a Monte Carlo style run with 100 samples, jut use `parfor ix = 1:100`, and Matlab will keep all of the workers busy until 100 executions have been completed.

Comment: Why do you regret running things as scripts instead of functions? I think depending on what you want to do with them and how much you need to edit them is the deciding factor on whether to run code as a script or as a function.
I would have used parfor but the simulator i'm using doesn't like parfor, which is why i'm using pctRunOnAll instead. 
Do you have any ideas on how to pass variables to workers though? My only solution, is to write data to a file and then get the workers to load the file. But i feel that this is a messy solution.

Comment: I usually regret running scripts for many reasons. Among them, the global workspace of scripts means that I always have hidden changes to variables, and it is difficult to manage inputs/outputs with respect to scripts. As you are finding here. It seems like the main problem you have is that `parfor` doesn't work. Why not? What do you mean "simulator I'm using doesn't like parfor"? It seems like a  fun hacking exercise to assign variables to workers without using the appropriate tools (functions and parfor), but I would hate to rely on it. (Also, I have not personally given it much thought.)

Comment: The simulator doesn't like parfor because it only wants to be instantiated once. Creating multiple instances of the simulator does not work and causes an error. Parfor does not work on a line by line simulation, because the instantiated simulator will only accept one simulation at a time. Therefore, using the simulator with parfor does not work and it can only work on multiple instances of MATLAB - hence pctRunOnAll. It's just the way the developer created the software.

Comment: Ps. pctRunOnAll is an appropriate tool. It's well documented within MATLAB.
And what you don't see is a higher level scripting that alters variables like the number of workers depending on the computer the work is computed on. And other such things that i haven't described. 
Therefore unrelated opinions is not appreciated.